# R: Animating vector of values

Tags: r, gganimate

I have two vectors of values (both of length 400, y1 and y2). For this moment I am starting to work with gganimation, so I only have two steps of animation, to work it out. In first step I have two series: vectors of y1 and y2 (values from 1 to 400 in my df) and in second step they change their values (values from 401 to 800 in my df). I would like to animate it like: first step: 400 points, second step: 400 points moved for different values.
I tried to do it in this way: I created a data frame, which at the point of transition looks like this:

```
    step   x           y1            y2
397    1 397 9.294785e-09 -5.109852e-09
398    1 398 9.861927e-09 -3.904613e-09
399    1 399 1.027354e-08 -2.637797e-09
400    1 400 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
401    2   1 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
402    2   2 0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
403    2   3 1.672068e-03  4.293141e-04
```

My code is:

```
g <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y1), size = 3, color = "black") +
     geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y2), size = 3, color = "red") +  transition_time(step)
animate(g)
```

I thought it will treat it like a transition for points from step 1 to step 2, but it shows both "series" (step 1 and 2) and there is no animation. How can I solve it? I thought about placing vectors in df, but not sure if it could work either. Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I suggest before asking a new question, you take the time to thank the people who answered your previous questions by accepting their answers and maybe upvoting.  Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers